# Flask set cookie even before Response instance created

Tags: python, class, flask, cookies

I want to set cookie if a variable is not None, here is my code

```
def get_user(user_id: int):
  auth = request.environ['auth']
  freshToken = request.environ['freshToken']
  try:
    # Authentication check
    if auth is None:
      raise UnauthorizedException('Invalid token.')
    user = User.get_by_identity(auth['identity'])

    # Authorization check...

    # Database query...

    resp = ApiResponse(200, 'success', 'User retrieved successfully.', queriedUser.to_mongo())
    if freshToken:
      resp.set_cookie('auth',freshToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
  except Exception as e:
    resp = ApiResponse(500, 'fa**strong text**il', f'Internal server error.', None)
    if isinstance(e, ClientError):
      resp = ApiResponse(e.code, 'fail', e.message, None)
      if freshToken:
        resp.set_cookie('auth',freshToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
  return resp
```

ApiResponse is inheritanced by flask Response class.

As you see, I need to create ApiResponse instance every time I want set cookie, the possible freshToken value is None or string, I want set cookie if freshToken contains value even before the Response instance created. So I expect I can just return like this:

```
return ApiResponse(200, 'success', 'User retrieved successfully.', queriedUser.to_mongo(), freshToken) # The cookie will be set if freshToken is not None.
```

Instead of nested messy code like this:

```
resp = ApiResponse(e.code, 'fail', e.message, None)
if freshToken:
  resp.set_cookie('auth',freshToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
return resp
```

Here is my ApiResponse class:

```
from flask import Response
from bson.json_util import dumps


class ApiResponse(Response):
  def __init__(self, code: int, state: str, message: str, data=None):
    response = {
      'state': state,
      'message': message,
      'data': data
    }

    response = dumps(response)

    super().__init__(response=response, status=code,
                     mimetype='application/json')
```

Tell me if you need more info.